# Ubuntu 16.04: error installing package ess

Tags: package-management

I have problems with installing package `ess` in Ubuntu Xenial.

For instance, if I try the command below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ess --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for ess:amd64
```

If I try the other command below:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ess
```

I get:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ess is broken or not fully installed.
```

I have no clue what's going on and would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe a glitch with the download mirror. Open _Software & Updates_ and change download server to find out.

Comment: Did you add the CRAN package repository to your apt sources?